# SMART test passed but I can see Hard Disk Broken Sectors in Disk Assesment

Tags: fsck, badblocks, smart, shred

I have used `shred` on my HDD, but in the middle of that, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination accidentally. After that I noticed bad sectors on Disk Assessment. I am using Linux mint 18 as my OS.

Using `fsck`, I tried to fix the broken sectors. I have rebooted the system , again I can see bad sectors on Disk Assessment

After I while I formatted my HD with zeros. After that the broken sectors got increased. I ran `SMART`, both short and long DST got passed. Still I can see bad sectors on Disk Assessment.

Comment: Your disk is dying.  Buy a new one, be happy the old one didn't crash while you still had useful data on it, and reconsider the amount of faith you put in SMART (i.e. SMART can _sometimes_ tell you that your disk is dying; it can't reliably tell you that your disk is ok).

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without seeing the actual SMART output, but many disks have broken sectors, which are flagged as soon as they are discovered. They are discovered when accessing them, so writing zeroes to your harddisk can increase the bad sector count (but the sectors have already been bad before).

It's next to impossible to *create* bad sectors by interrupting a command (with ctrl-c, or otherwise). It's also not possible not "fix" bad sectors using fsck.

You can force remapping of bad sectors by writing to them (e.g. `dd` with **correct** sector address), which you already did using `shred`. But given you want to shred the disk anyway, there's no need to fix anything.

If you are really paranoid about the data on your disk, shred it physically (open it up, use an axe, strong magenet, or whatever).

Comment: I was about to take the laptop to a service center to fix a keyboard issue actually. Before that I thought of shredding the data. I doubt that it is logical damage to the disk. Could you please give me some idea about the force remapping?

Comment: Writing zeroes to all sectors should be all you need, the service center isn't going to have an electron microscope to recover data on bad sectors, nor will they invest the effort just for fun. I'm not sure what you mean by "logical damage". And yes, the bad sectors will stay bad, even after they get remapped. Depending on what SMART says, you may want to get a new harddisk, if it's too many bad sectors.

Comment: I was referring to this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/550448/395017 . But I was not able to see any bad blocks. This confused me again

Comment: There are two machinisms to hadle bad blocks: By the (1) harddisk itself, and by the (2) ext filesystem. (1) The harddisk can reallocate blocks ("use block 456 whenever the computer access block 123, because block 123 is bad"), and the number of those reallocations is shown in `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`. All of these were bad sectors originally. (2) The filesystem can ignore blocks that are known to be bad. If the harddisk itself can reallocate bad blocks anyway, using this feature is a bad idea, so usually this list should be left empty.

Comment: Sorry for asking more questions to your answers @dirkt. The badblocks command give me 0 bad block. Whether it means that my HD doesn't contain any bad sectors?

Comment: @dasrohith It means a simple read doesn't detect any CRC error for the remaining blocks.  Like I said: if the number of bad blocks has been increasing recently, it's time to get a new disk.  You _will_ start running into irrecoverable errors soon if you don't.

Comment: If the badblocks command gives you 0 sectors *now*, it means that *now* all sectors read fine, because the bad sectors have been remapped after they were discovered by writing zeros to then. If you had run the badsectors command *before* writing the zeroes, you'd have seen bad sectors. Look at `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` in the SMART output. That's the amount of remapped bad sectors you have. And post the complete SMART output, then we can actually decide if the disk is going bad or not, instead of just guessing.